# Does quantum complementarity inherently require ensembles?

Tags: quantum-interpretations

If there are two complementary observables, $P$ and $Q$, it does superficially appear as if the only kind of empirical evidence we can get for complementarity has to come from statistical data from an ensemble of quantum states, with $P$ measured in a fraction of the sample, and $Q$ in the other fraction. This is due to measurement disturbance as well as our lack of empirical access to counterfactual "realities".

Are there any loopholes allowing us to demonstrate complementarity for a *single* quantum state?

In particular, does complementarity apply to our universe as a whole, or does it require a multiverse? If some kind of event occurs with multiple "identical" copies within the universe, maybe the collection of these events can be treated as an ensemble, but what about very rare quantum events in our universe?

Or take the example of black hole complementarity with Alice jumping into a black hole, and having subjective experiences inside, while Bob outside observes that all the quantum information about Alice is encoded unitarily within the external Hawking radiation. Can we only have complementarity if we have an ensemble of black holes and Alices with identical microstates? Even then, to actually obtain empirical evidence for complementarity, we would have to jump into a fraction of the black holes, but after jumping into even a single black hole, we no longer have access to any *other* black hole interiors. Does this mean that black hole complementarity has no empirical consequences? According to the philosophy of positivism, does that make black hole complementarity meaningless?

Comment: It would help if you included a definition of *"complementary observable"* in your question, because it is not very easy to search for.

Comment: @ACuriousMind Well, I can't think up of a "black hole complementarity observable", and that's the problem. What would positivists say?

Comment: But for ensembles, I just defined a "complementarity observable", at least if we dismiss conspiracy theories about Nature.